# Can you easily subtract two 2-dimensional arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

An implementation for a complex formula requires me to explode a series of strings and values into a 2 dimensional array. Another 2 dimensional array of the same size (containing same value types) is generated dynamically. I'm wondering if it is an easy feat in Java to subtract the 2 matrices without having to iterate through them value by value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Commons Math library. For example:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/Array2DRowRealMatrix.html#subtract(org.apache.commons.math3.linear.Array2DRowRealMatrix)

Comment: Thank you, I found that helpful.